# Yaml Based Selector For Go Structures

Tags: go, yaml

For structures with definitions for unmarshaling from yaml

```golang
type Complex struct {
  Im float `yaml:"im"`
  Re float `yaml:"re"`
}
type A struct {
   Property int `yaml:"prop"`
   Items []*Complex `yaml:"items"`
}

type B struct {
   Nested *A `yaml:"sub"`
}
```

Is there a way to resolve a value from instantiated variable e.g.

```golang
var b B = initiateWhatever()
```

based on a path for yaml space (not the go property names)

```golang
targetValue := resolve(b, "sub.prop")
```

Or maybe there's even any tools for that available making even complex selections just as `jq` does for json or `yq` for yaml. But still the idea is to manipulate not serialized data but instantiated structure it self

```golang
itemReals := resolve(b, "sub.items[*].re") // array of floats desired here
```

Comment: Go is a static language.  Its `struct`s do not act like, say, javascript objects.  You fight against the language when you try to make struct field names dynamic.  You can do it though, with reflect.

Comment: If you deserialize to `yaml.Node` instead of specific structs, you'll have a generic data structure where you can easily implement something like this. There isn't an existing API for it though; yq has a [request for a public API](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/831).